# Kotlin for android - first button works, second doesn't?

Tags: kotlin

im trying to code a really simple app, it's my first one for android.
In the console i don't get any error messages but when i try to run the app on android emulator i can only press the first button and get to the activity i want, second doenst work. Maybe you can help me.
Thats my code:

```
    val button = findViewById<Button>(Btn)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(Btn2)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity3::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }
    }
}
```

}

What am i missing? Thank you in adavance!

Comment: You're setting the second button listener when the first button is clicked. Move it out one block.

Answer (score 0):

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(Btn)
button.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}


val button = findViewById<Button>(Btn2)
button.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity3::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the second button and setting the Listener to it inside the listener of the first button

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(Btn)
button.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}


val button2 = findViewById<Button>(Btn2)
button2.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity3::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After `startActivity(intent)` you need a "}"

Answer (score 0):

If you write it this way, you can only press the BTN button first before the second btn2 button is set and can be clicked later, so you should write the btn2 code logic outside, like this

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(Btn)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }


    val button = findViewById<Button>(Btn2)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity3::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've got the answer from community, I'll join))

Move the second button's logic outta first one.

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(Btn1)
button.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}


val button = findViewById<Button>(Btn2)
button.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity3::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Hope, `findViewById` method soon will be deprecated.